# Detecting overflow with right-aligned element next to it

Tags: html, css

I have table headers with a right-aligned down arrow to indicate when the table is sorted by that column. These columns can be resized, and I need to display a tooltip on mouseover if the header is overflowing and thus truncated with `...`. I cannot figure out how to properly detect overflow in this instance, however. I've tried two methods: floating the arrow to the right and positioning with flexbox.

#### [Here's a fiddle with both methods.](https://jsfiddle.net/vaindil/ezjv9hcg/6/)

Column 2 in that fiddle has a right-floated arrow, column 3 uses flex. Problems:

- Using float doesn't cause a difference between `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth` until the column is so narrow that the overflow extends beyond the floated element. You can see this in that fiddle by changing `#col-2` to a width of `60px`. The text is properly truncated, but those widths can't be used reliably.
- Using flex, `offsetWidth` and `scrollWidth` are always the same regardless of column width. The text is truncated properly with `...`, but those two properties are never different.

How can I properly detect overflow with the layout given in that example? **I do not want any method that involves cloning the element. My stylesheets are too complicated for that method to work, and its performance is terrible anyway.**

The code from the fiddle is below just so it's included in this question as well.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.ellipsis-overflow').forEach((el) => {
  if (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
    el.style.color = 'red';
  }
});
```

```css
#col-2 {
  width: 80px; /* set to 60px to trigger overflow detection */
}

#col-3 {
  width: 80px;
}

.float i {
  float: right;
}

span.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

span.flex-container i {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.ellipsis-overflow {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis-overflow * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* below this is just style stuff to make the problem easier to see */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

i.material-icons {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<p>Column text will be red if <code>offsetWidth</code> is less than
<code>scrollWidth</code>, indicating overflow. Trigger this in column 2 by setting
its width to 60px.</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th id="col-2" class="float">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          Column 2
        </span>
      </th>
      <th id="col-3">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <span class="flex-container">
            <span>Column 3</span>
            <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Original Answer**

You can set the `overflow: auto` before the condition and set it back to `hidden` after the condition. :)

See the Snippet below (I have set the `col-2` width to `60px`):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.ellipsis-overflow').forEach((el) => {
  el.style.overflow = "auto";
  if (el.offsetWidth < el.scrollWidth) {
    el.style.color = 'red';
  }
  el.style.overflow = "hidden";
});
```

```css
#col-2 {
  width: 60px; /* set to 60px to trigger overflow detection */
}

#col-3 {
  width: 80px;
}

.float i {
  float: right;
}

span.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

span.flex-container i {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.ellipsis-overflow {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis-overflow * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* below this is just style stuff to make the problem easier to see */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

i.material-icons {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<p>Column text will be red if <code>offsetWidth</code> is less than
<code>scrollWidth</code>, indicating overflow. Trigger this in column 2 by setting
its width to 60px.</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th id="col-2" class="float">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          Column 2
        </span>
      </th>
      <th id="col-3">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <span class="flex-container">
            <span>Column 3</span>
            <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**Updated Answer**

I think you can do the same check with the parent Height.

See the Snippet below:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('span.ellipsis-overflow').forEach((el) => {
 var initialHeight = el.parentElement.clientHeight;
 el.classList.add("letMeCheckWidth");
 if (initialHeight  < el.parentElement.clientHeight) {
   el.style.color = 'red';
  }
 el.classList.remove("letMeCheckWidth");
});
```

```css
#col-2 {
  width: 80px; /* set to 60px to trigger overflow detection */
}

#col-3 {
  width: 80px;
}

.float i {
  float: right;
}

span.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

span.flex-container i {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.ellipsis-overflow {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ellipsis-overflow * {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.ellipsis-overflow.letMeCheckWidth {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: normal;
}

.ellipsis-overflow.letMeCheckWidth * {
  overflow: auto;
  text-overflow: inherit;
  white-space: normal;
}

/* below this is just style stuff to make the problem easier to see */

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 400px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

i.material-icons {
  font-size: 16px !important;
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<p>Column text will be red if <code>offsetWidth</code> is less than <code>scrollWidth</code>, indicating overflow. Trigger this in column 2 by setting its width to 60px.</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th id="col-2" class="float">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          Column 2
        </span>
      </th>
      <th id="col-3">
        <span class="ellipsis-overflow">
          <span class="flex-container">
            <span>Column 3</span>
            <i class="material-icons">arrow_downward</i>
          </span>
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

You can test it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/6x3fuhcp/) also..

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. `none` isn't a valid option for `overflow`, and using this anyway doesn't change the text to red when the width is 80px like it should.

Comment: My bad!! not `none` but `auto`.. but agreed to you. checking for the better one!

Comment: @vaindil: I have updated the answer.. Please check the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/6x3fuhcp/)